# What is wrong with my Python code(beginner)?

Tags: python

```
print 'Welcome to the Pig Latin Translator!'

original = raw_input("Enter a Word:")
if len(original) > 0 :
print original 
else : 
    print "Empty!"
```

Comment: please fix the formatting and tell us what error you get...

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3? And Please share the traceback.

Comment: You did not indent after the if statement. (The edit I made only placed the code into a code block, this is the original format)

Comment: Thank you guys for quick reply!
I played along with my code a bit and discovered that it didnt work just because the word "print" needed 4 blanks before itself!
Is my above conclusion correct? (Pardon me Im 5 days old to Python)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Indentation needed after the if statement.

```
print 'Welcome to the Pig Latin Translator!'

original = raw_input("Enter a Word:")
if len(original) > 0 :
    print original 
else : 
    print "Empty!"
```

Comment: It would be better if you could also add the code.

Comment: Hey there, I just copied your code and it worked!
Sorry , but I still don't get where my indentation went wrong and yours went correct !?